# How to attach One Event Handler to different Inputs in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am new to react js.

I have several inputs in my form and considering controllable input approach in React , I am trying to do the job with one event handler to every other inputs. I took some references in stack overflow and come to this. Still not able to figure it out why I am unable to write inside my input box.

Here is my code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col , Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class ContactForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '' ,
      email: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
          <input name="input1"  value={this.state.name}  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <input name="input2" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <p>{this.state.name}, {this.state.email}</p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}


export default ContactForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `name` attribute to identify the input, but you're reading the wrong values in the render function, "name" and "email" instead of "input1" and "input2"

You can do this instead:

```
<input name="input1"  value={this.state.input1}  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
<input name="input2" value={this.state.input2} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

or

```
<input name="name"  value={this.state.name}  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
<input name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

You'd also have to change this :

```
this.state = {
  name: '' ,
  email: ''
};
```

in the constructor if you're using the first option.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ref to achieve this:

```
handleChange(e) {
      const {input1, input2} = this.refs;
      //do what ever you want with the values

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
          <input name="input1"  value={this.state.name} ref="input1" />
          <input name="input2" value={this.state.email} ref="input2" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <p>{this.state.name}, {this.state.email}</p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, I would use a submit button, or something like that, instead of an event listener on one or two of the inputs